# Dynamic Array Allocation confusion

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, dynamic-arrays

I am to read in several values from the user and store those in an array. Then I need to create an array which is big enough to store all those values. Using some functions I wrote I sort/lsearch/bsearch through the array for given values.

I already have my program written and everything, but for a static array implementation. I am sort of getting confused on where to actually use the dynamic array.

It makes sense to use it when the user starts entering values, since I can't assume how many values he enters, so the array needs to be big enough to hold it. It also makes sense (Sort of) to use it when I am creating a big enough array that can hold all the value (Acts as a copy of the first array).

I'm not asking for any code, everything is done but on a static approach. I am just trying to visualize where I would need to use darrays here. My thoughts are:

1. When the user first enters the values
2. When i copy arr1 into a new arr2 that needs to be big enough to hold all of arr1's values.

Am I right or wrong on this?

Comment: Show what you have. It is not quite clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: you need calloc and realloc

Comment: Since you need to accommodate input of a size that you cannot reliably predict (a bound on) at compile time, you need to use a dynamic data structure to store the initial input.  You'll need to expand it at need while reading the input.  If you need to make a copy of the input data then you need a second dynamic data structure to hold it, but you may not need ever to resize that one.  Dynamically-allocated arrays are one variety of potentially-suitable data structure; there are others.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using `malloc` or `calloc` to allocate an array of some known starting size, and keep track of the current capacity in a variable.

As you're reading values in, if your array isn't big enough, then user `realloc` to double the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ask the wrong question.

The question is:
Is a dynamic array (a contiguous block of memory) the proper data structure to hold and process the data in your application?

There is only one especially useful application for arrays and that is as associative array, which means that the array index itself has a meaning and can be used to retrieve the correct contents you are searching with an effort of O(1).

In example, a list of track runners could be stored in an array, where the array index equals the track number. This is the perfect data structure if you want to visualize the name of the runners per track. It's a terrible data structure if you want to alphabetically sort the names of all runners.

But according to your application description, the array index has no meaning for you. This is an indication that an array is not the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is not to copy the entire array each time a user inputs a value.  The demands on malloc and free will be heavy, and get worse with larger arrays.

You need to calculate the size of your array with "number of elements as the input

int* array = newArray(10);

int* newArray(int size) {
   return malloc(size * sizeof(int));
}

Keep in mind that an `int*` is an array, so you can still do `array[3]`.  But, if you centralize the storage of number of used elements and the current size, you can allocate a few elements and only grow when the available elements are exhausted.

```
struct DynamicIntArray {
  int used;
  int size;
  int* storage
};

void add(struct DynamicArray* array, int value) {
  if (used < size) {
    (*array).storage[used] = value;
    used++;
  } else {
    int newSize = size+10;
    int* newStorage = (int*)malloc(newSize*sizeof(int));
    int* oldStorage = (*array).storage;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       newStorage[i] = oldStorage[i];
    }
    (*array).storage = newStorage;
    (*array).size = newSize;
    free(oldStorage);
  }
}
```

with such an example.  You should be able to write the `newDynamicIntArray(...)` function and the `freeDynamicIntArray(struct DynamicIntArray* array)` function and any other methods you care about.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure how many entries inserted at runtime i suggest you to use linked list data structure. It will save your memory usage.

Comment: Searching a linked list is `O(n)`.